# How to apply different css margin-top to each children in a list

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have the following code:

```
function computeSetImgMargins(iD) {
 var ids = iD;
 var totalWidth = 0
 var totalHeight = 0;
 ids.children().each(function(index){
     var imgWidth = ids.children().width();
     var imgHeight = ids.children().height();
     totalWidth += imgWidth;
     totalHeight += imgHeight;
     var leftMargin = imgWidth - totalWidth;
     var topMargin = imgHeight - totalHeight;
     ids.children(index).css('margin-left',leftMargin);
     ids.children(index).css('margin-top',topMargin);
   });
}
var objLi = jquery("li", this);
computeSetImgMargins(objLi);
```

My Html has something like this

```
<div id="imgrt">
<ul id="if">
   <li><img src="../pictures/album/20-c-44.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="../pictures/album/20-c-44.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I don't have separate ID's or classes for each element. I'm not sure if that would be a good idea (would be open to comments), but without using that how do I apply different margin-left and margin-top position to each `<li>`, and `<img>` elements in `<ul>`?

This I guess would overlap both the images.

My CSS for `<ul>` is the following:

```
#if { left: 0%; top: 0%; margin: 5px; padding: 5px; position: relative; width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: #101010; z-index: 30; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of `ids.children()` use `$(this)`.  Within the each, `$(this)` will give you the current item in the loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/nvnTW/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fixed that, but i'm seeing that it is still not applying my style to each of the li element.Infact i also tried using the appendTo function and still no luck. Here is what i tried jquery(this).css('margin-top',topMargin).appendTo(this);

Comment: Not sure exactly what your intent is here, because it seems odd to put negative margins on them, but it does work with this:  http://jsfiddle.net/nvnTW/  You would not want appendTo though, you're trying to append an item to itself.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Its my bad, i didn't logically understand what you were trying to explain. in the .each, i still should be using ids.children().each, and inside each it should have been jquery9this0 to refer to each individual element. I had done jquery(this).each(function(index){...} which is why it was not working, my bad. Thanks for helping again +1